# Firebase Auth Can't Login

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I was trying to integrate Firebase Authentication into my first Firebase App but was having a weird issue. I integrated Firebase Auth into my Login Activity with a Login and Signup Feature, but whenever I try to test the app out and try to Sign-Up a dummy user, nothing happens and the intent to InfoActivity is not run.

My code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    EditText email;

    EditText password;

    String emailString;

    String passwordString;

    Button login;

    TextView signUp;

    int status = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);

        password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);

        signUp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signUp);

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                emailString = email.getText().toString().trim();

                passwordString = password.getText().toString().trim();

                if (status == 0) {

                    loginMethod(emailString, passwordString)

                } else if (status == 1) {

                    signUpMethod(emailString, passwordString);

                }

            }
        });

        signUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (status == 0) {

                    status = 1;

                    login.setText("Sign Up");

                    signUp.setText("Login");

                } else if (status == 1) {

                    status = 0;

                    login.setText("Login");

                    signUp.setText("Sign Up");

                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void loginMethod(String email, String password) {


        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Log.i("Task:", "Complete");

                            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);

                            startActivity(i);

                        }

                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Login Failed",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }
                });

    }

    public void signUpMethod(String email, String password) {

        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, InfoActivity.class);

                    startActivity(i);
                }

                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Sign Up Failed",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I already have Firebase Auth working in the iOS Version of my app, but surprisingly, it is not working on the Android Version. Can any of you please help me get this setup?

Comment: are you sure that the `Email/Password` sign-in method is enabled in your firebase console?

Comment: Yes, Email Password Login is enabled

Comment: okay, on signing up, are you getting this Toast `"Sign Up Failed"`?

Comment: Nope, nothing at all

Comment: is your app working for signing process? also, try to see what's there in `task` `(task.getMessage())` that will give you some idea about what's going wrong

Comment: The app doesn't work for the login process either. I will check the task.getmessage() and let you know.

Comment: Hi, the code for the onComplete Listener is not run. Can you please help? Thanks

Comment: I am too having the same issue. I think its because firebase suspended our device due to massive login try while developing.

Comment: I don't remember exactly how I fixed the issue but I think it was something like changing some code and some settings in the console. I can share my current code if needed.

Comment: check your google play services is updated? if notyou will also get notification for that.

Comment: Hi, I was able to fix the issue. Thanks for your help.